# Logic for ignoring the duplicate key without altering the table SQL

Tags: sql-server

**QUESTION(1):**

Is it possible to create a try-catch that inserts a set of codes and when an error is thrown

(Example: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CouponNumber'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CouponNumber'.`),

it will just skip that value and continue inserting the rest of the codes?

My current code is a SP something like this:

```
 DECLARE @Success    BIT
    SELECT @RetryCount = 1, @Success = 0
    WHILE @Success = 0
    BEGIN
       BEGIN TRY
          BEGIN TRANSACTION

          CREATE TABLE dbo.RandomGenerator(
              RowNumber INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
              NextID INT )
          ;WITH x AS (
             SELECT TOP (1000000) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
             FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 
             CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
             ORDER BY s1.[object_id] 
          )
          INSERT dbo.RandomGenerator(RowNumber, NextID)
          SELECT rn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) + 1000000 FROM x;

          INSERT  INTO dbo.RandomNumbers( EventID, RandomID, UserID)
             SELECT TOP (@Number) @EventID, NextID, @UserID FROM RandomGenerator

          COMMIT TRANSACTION

          SELECT 'Success!'
          SELECT @Success = 1 -- To exit the loop
       END TRY

       BEGIN CATCH
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

          SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS [Error Number],
          ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ErrorMessage];     

          IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 2627
          BEGIN
              --Do Something...
          END 
       END CATCH
    END
```

And what it does is simply generate and try and try until success.

I'm planning to try to insert all the numbers without duplicate and if then repeat the process until the count of the inserted numbers is equal to @Number.

And while creating this question, I found a related question where they use IGNORE_KEY_DUP. I would like to try it but I can't because I cannot alter the table...

**QUESTION(2):**
Is there a way to use IGNORE_KEY_UP without altering the table?

Advance thanks!

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that I already tried the NOT EXIST and NOT IN during insert but its so slow specially if there is 100,000+ randomIDs existing in the table. So I removed it as my option, and I think try and try until successful insert is much faster than comparing each a 100,000 new randomID from the existing 1M randomIDs.

**EDIT:**

Apparently my boss just allowed to alter the table for the meantime. So here is what I've achieved

```
Duplicate key was ignored.
@newCouponCount727012       @generatedCount:227012      @notGeneratedCount:22988
Duplicate key was ignored.
@newCouponCount747842       @generatedCount:247842      @notGeneratedCount:2158
Duplicate key was ignored.
@newCouponCount749846       @generatedCount:249846      @notGeneratedCount:154
Duplicate key was ignored.
@newCouponCount749991       @generatedCount:249991      @notGeneratedCount:9
@newCouponCount750000       @generatedCount:250000      @notGeneratedCount:0
```

. This runs in 14sec compared to the 30min+ when using `NOT EXISTS` This is what I meant by try and try until succeed. I know this is conflicting to the title of my question so I would still gladly accept answers/ new approach, in case the IGNORE_DUP_KEY would end up producing more bugs.

Comment: It would really help, if you explained a bit more what your are trying to achieve. I'm pretty sure, that there will be a better approach (read about the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Provide a *commented expected output*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your question (1), you could just exclude the duplicated result into your WHERE clause. Since we don't have the query on `dbo.CouponNumber` I can only give you an example:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (MyPKColumn1, MyPKColumn2)
SELECT RowNumber, NextID
FROM   dbo.RandomGenerator
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                    FROM dbo.MyTable As excludeTbl
                    WHERE excludeTbl.MyPKColumn1 = RowNumber 
                      AND excludeTbl.MyPKColumn2 = NextID  )
```

As for your question (2), IGNORE_KEY_UP  is an index option. Meaning, you can set it only when creating/altering your index. Depending on what you mean by "altering your table", you have your answer. Theoretically, altering an index doesn't alter a table. (Beware unique indexes and primary key aren't index only.)

EDIT :

Considering you already give NOT EXISTS a try. I will tell you that it exists 3 approach to excluding value that I know of : NOT IN, NOT EXISTS, LEFT JOIN ON NULL VALUE.

You should try the 3 of them before going for IGNORE_KEY_UP. IGNORE_KEY_UP with time will give you a lot of problems.

An example of LEFT JOIN ON NULL VALUE :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (MyPKColumn1, MyPKColumn2)
SELECT rg.RowNumber, rg.NextID
FROM   dbo.RandomGenerator rg
LEFT JOIN dbo.MyTable  mt
    ON  rg.RowNumber = mt.MyPKColumn1 
    AND rg.NextID  = mt.MyPKColumn2
WHERE  mt.MyPKColumn1 IS NULL
  AND  mt.MyPKColumn2 IS NULL
```

EDIT 2:

About IGNORE_KEY_UP. Where could it be a problem?

Their is a lot of reason to never use IGNORE_KEY_UP but I'm no specialist to this particular reason. I can give you only 3 main reasons:

- It would break any logic using UNICITY asumption on indexed columns. Reworded : You just break the UNIQUE/PK part of an index and will never be able to expect only one record given a filter on this index. Using so, you will need to check every existing code filtering on your indexed columns for them not to expect only one record.
- IGNORE_KEY_UP will slow down INSERT or UPDATE on your indexed columns. Because it could reorganize your index B-Tree each time inserted in a full leaf.
- It could lightly slow down your access time on indexed columns with duplicated values.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already tried the NOT EXIST and NOT IN during insert but its so slow specially if there is 100,000+ randomIDs existing in the table. So I removed it as my option, and I think try and try until successful insert is much faster than comparing each a 100,000 new randomID from the existing 1M randomIDs. @Shnugo

Comment: I'm thinking to mark this as answer because I used the IGNORE_KEY_DUP and it works. And I like what you said "Altering an index doesn't alter a table", my mistake for thinking that it is the same.

Comment: Well it's not true nor wrong to say "Altering an index doesn't alter a table". You can see an index as an independant B-Tree that will be updated each time a DML request goes on the table. If one of the B-Tree fail to update the table fails too. (for example because of unicity constraint : PK/UK.) Which mean altering an index will "Alter DML request accepted by the table". (DML request are Update, Insert, Delete requests.)

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late reply. Can you please explain to me exactly what are the disadvantages of IGNORE_KEY_DUP. I tried to google it and it says it is not advisable in a large database/ large chance of duplicates. But I tried to run my SP and generate 1M randomIDs (1min 7sec) over 1M randomIDs (1min 14sec) over 1M random IDs (1min 15sec) and it works just fine with no problems, although it prints the warning multiple times:

Comment: This is when I generate 1M randomID on a 1M existing ID (runtime 1min,14sec)

`Duplicate key was ignored.
newCouponCount1987656  generatedCount:987656  notGeneratedCount:12344
Duplicate key was ignored.
newCouponCount1999701  generatedCount:999701  notGeneratedCount:299
Duplicate key was ignored.
newCouponCount1999995  generatedCount:999995  notGeneratedCount:5
Duplicate key was ignored.
newCouponCount1999999  generatedCount:999999  notGeneratedCount:1
newCouponCount2000000  generatedCount:1000000  notGeneratedCount:0`

on first try, there are `12344` duplicates and so on..

Comment: The problem is conceptual. In the first place why do you have a PK/UK if you got a IGNORE_KEY_UP? In most case, it doesn't make sense at best.
The performance problem is more at Insert/Update time when in between values: For example, If you got 1 id (integer) column containing 1 to 2000. Inserting duplicates values between 1000 to 1100 could take an unexpected long time.
Added an edit for more problem information about IGNORE_KEY_UP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I really understand what you want...

If I got this right, you need many unique random numbers. The following code will create a quasi-random list by casting the first 4 byte of a `NEWID()` to an `INT`. `ABS` will turn neagtive values to positive. By using `DISTINCT` there is no repeated number and this is fast...

Looking for 100.000 random numbers returned 99.997 in no time.

```
DECLARE @Count INT=100000;
WITH 
 Tally(Nr)    AS(SELECT TOP(@Count) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values CROSS JOIN master..spt_values x CROSS JOIN master..spt_values y)
,Randoms(Rnd) AS(SELECT DISTINCT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT)) FROM Tally)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      ,Rnd
FROM  Randoms
```

You might add something like `WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable WHERE ExistingCode=Rnd)` to make sure, that the list returned will not include existing numbers... This you can insert *as-is*, no loop needed...

Comment: I tried your code, but instead of `ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT))` I used `ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT))` so it would return an 8-digit random (1XXXXXXX) but it returned only one value?

Comment: @Cyberpau Sorry, I do not understand you... This is both the same? What do you think by *8-digit-random-number*? What is *but it returned only one value*? If you test my code, you'll get a long list of values... Btw: One thing for sure: Your idea *I think try and try until successful* is - for sure!!! - wrong. A set based approach must be better than a procedural one for such an issue.

Comment: Apologies, copy pasting from VM sometimes fails. What I meant is that I used this code: `10000000 + (CONVERT(BIGINT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4,0x25F18060 )) % 10000000)` instead of `NEWID()`, kindly try running it and it will return only one row. My boss just allowed me to alter the table using IGNORE_DUP_KEY and I just solved my problem, I'll add the edit now.